# How to calculate the length in pixels of a string with php - from another page on my website

Tags: php, html, css

I want to dynamically generate some of the the css for a web page, using php. 
I am going to use a php page as the css document, to dynamically set some css values for a menu bar on the web page.
The php in the css is going to set the width of the li containers for each of the top level menu links.
Each li contain just one top level link, and each li is going to have a different width based on the width of the text in the link it contain.

So when a page on the website loads, I want the php on the css page to retrieve the width of each of the top level a elements of the menu bar.
Then I want the php in the css to set the width of the li element surrounding each of the a elements.
And then the website will be displayed.

But how do I calculate the width of the text of each of the -a- elements on the web page, from within the php css page? 
The css is on one page and the html is on another, on the same domain.
And I don't need get the width of the sub menu links - or the li elements.

Here is how the menu bar is structured in html

```
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
  <li class="first"><a href="page1.php">Page 1</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="page1b.php">Sub menu 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="page2.php">Page 2</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="submenu2.php">Submenu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You would need to run a browser on your server via something like selenium to get the rendered width of an element - there probably is a much simpler way to achieve the same goal.

Comment: or what about phantomJS omg!!!

Comment: You are working backwards my friend

Comment: If this is hopeless, then I am glad I got the help to find that out :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for deterring me from this dead-end.
It helped me find the solution - using either tables or flexbox in css. That gives me the dynamical style I need for the menu elements.

http://www.sitepoint.com/responsive-fluid-width-variable-item-navigation-css/

Answer (score 6):

This is somewhere between difficult, infeasible and nonsensical. PHP has nothing to do at all with how the content is going to be displayed. The browser on the client end is going to actually render the text in a specific font in whatever settings the client may have applied (e.g. 200% text size for the visually impaired). PHP **cannot** know this. PHP **cannot** predict this. PHP **cannot** reach into the browser to figure out what it's going to look like.

If anything, client-side Javascript can inspect the rendered element to see what width it's being rendered at finally. It could send that information back to PHP via AJAX, but that's most likely madness. Don't bother server-side code with client-side issues. If you need to do something programmatically with the rendered width, do it in Javascript in the browser.

Comment: If php can't calculate the width in pixels of a known string, when knowing the font and font size (as the font and its properties is defined in the css), then I have to find another solution.

Comment: The problem is you *won't* know exactly the font and font size, since the client has the final say. Also, fonts aren't rendered pixel perfect identically between different clients; there's a wide range of possible differences in how a specific font is going to be rendered. The solution you discovered is a lot saner than trying to pre-calculate anything server-side.